# Cosmos DB "In" operator SQL Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a requirement to query by documents (cosmos DB) based on unique key in batch request.

My approach to above requirement

1. Since my key say customerId  is unique I am making customerId as Id and Partition key also as /id.
2. Since its batch read request (25 calls/per request and 10 batch requests/sec) , I am utilizing “in” operator in SQL query and extracting all the documents by CosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery function
   Ex: my SQL query would look like “Select * from c where c.Id in (‘a1’,’b1’)
3. Following are my feed options:

   new FeedOptions
                                                             {
                                                                 MaxItemCount = -1,
                                                                     EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                                                                 MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1,
                                                                 MaxBufferedItemCount = -1
                                                     }

Based on the above scenario:

1. Am I actually  utilizing the query by Id functionality well to achieve faster response time?
2. Does EnableCrossPartitionQuery makes sense in the current scenario?
3. Am I doing partioning right?

Is there a better way I can utilize the capability of extracting the data is key value pair fashion?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Does EnableCrossPartitionQuery makes sense in the current scenario?

Yes.Since your partition key is unique id,you need `EnableCrossPartitionQuery =true` to make sure the query could scan all the partitions when you query `id` column.

> 2.Am I actually utilizing the query by Id functionality well to achieve
>   faster response time?Am I doing partioning right?

According to the scenario you mentioned in your question,i believe that you have already read Overview of [Choosing partition key in cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey).Since you set `MaxItemCount= -1`(return all the filter data without pagination),you have to balance the RUs settings following the rules mentioned in the above link:

> Azure Cosmos containers have a minimum throughput of 400 request units
>   per second (RU/s). When throughput is provisioned on a database,
>   minimum RUs per container is 100 request units per second (RU/s).
>   Requests to the same partition key can't exceed the throughput that's
>   allocated to a partition. If requests exceed the allocated throughput,
>   requests are rate-limited. So, it's important to pick a partition key
>   that doesn't result in "hot spots" within your application.

If you don't want to raise RUs settings,you may consider setting `MaxItemCount = some page` size and load all the data by `continuation token`.

> 3.Is there a better way I can utilize the capability of extracting the
>   data is key value pair fashion?

If your deviceIds have some common naming rules,maybe you could consider below 2 ideas:

1.Adjust the index policy of devideId following this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy

2.Try to create a synthetic partition key following this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys,for example,add some suffix before the devideId.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Gong. I will go through these links

Comment: @Sushma Sure,any concern,pls let me know.